# NullPointerException during gradle build on Windows

Tags: java, apache-pig, build.gradle

I am currently using **gradle** to build dependencies and I have added below statement in my **build.gradle** :

```
compile group: 'org.apache.pig', name:'pig', version:'0.12.0-cdh5.1.0'
testCompile group: 'org.apache.pig', name: 'pigunit', version:'0.12.0-cdh5.1.0'
```

Code is as below :

```
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.LOCAL);
final Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>(HASH_MAP_SIZE);
paramMap.put("input_path", args[0]);
paramMap.put("output_path", args[1]);
pigServer.setBatchOn();
InputStream is = PigExecutor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(args[0]);
pigServer.registerScript(is, paramMap);
```

while executing above code I am getting below issue :

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:DefaultJobName got an error while submitting 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)
```

Could someone provide me solution for this.

Comment: Doesnt look like an error in your code. Did you try re-running the job?

Comment: Before running the job, build should be successful..My build is getting failed.

Comment: Oh okay. Your question description does not say that your build is failing. I dont see a reason for getting NPE during build.

Comment: This issue comes on Windows machine only.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it applies to Pig, but perhaps its because hadoop istallation is missing winutis.exe

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10051

one place to get that exe:

http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/39/error-util-shell-failed-locate-winutils-binary-hadoop-binary-path

Comment: Thanks @andresv. I will get back after applying the solution.